# Webcam on Angström

Tags: linux, drivers, video, kernel-modules, camera

I am running [Angström](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/) on my [BeagleBoard-xm](http://beagleboard.org/hardware-xM). I want to use a webcam (I have Microsoft LifeCam Cinema and Logitech C310). I installed `v4l-utils`, `libv4l-dev` and `kernel-module-uvcvideo` with opkg. But the webcams don't appear in the `/dev` folder. `cheese` can't find them too.

Here is the output of `dmesg`:

```
[ 8925.347137] usb 2-2.4.3: new high speed USB device using ehci-omap and address 8
[ 8925.489044] usb 2-2.4.3: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=075d
[ 8925.496490] usb 2-2.4.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 8925.504333] usb 2-2.4.3: Product: Microsoft�� LifeCam Cinema(TM)
[ 8925.510528] usb 2-2.4.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[ 8926.635742] 8:3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
```

and here is the output of `lsusb`:

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04d9:1603 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 045e:075d Microsoft Corp.
```

uvcvideo kernel module seems to be in the right folder:

```
# locate uvcvideo.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.32/kernel/drivers/media/video/uvc/uvcvideo.ko

# uname -a
Linux beagleboard 2.6.32 #3 PREEMPT Tue Jul 26 10:56:56 CEST 2011 armv7l unknown
```

`lsmod`output is:

```
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ipv6                  249063  10
```

But I don't see uvcvideo module in the `lsmod` output. Should I do something else to load the module? Or should I install a specific driver?

Comment: Did you try checking `lsmod` output after an `modprobe uvcvideo`?

Comment: @dkaragasidis I get `FATAL: Module uvcvideo not found.`

Comment: Can your verify that uvcvideo.ko exists on your system and _it is_ compiled against the kernel version you're running (with `modinfo`)?

Comment: @dkaragasidis yes, it's in the folder `/lib/modules/2.6.32/kernel/drivers/media/video/` and there is a line `vermagic:       2.6.32 preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7`

Comment: Great. Can you try and load the module using `insmod` followed by the absolute path of uvcvideo.ko? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: thanks, it worked! Where should I add this command to be initialized every time at boot?

Comment: Generally, when you want a kernel module to be loaded at boot time, you append the kernel module name to `/etc/modules` or `/etc/modules.conf` (_might vary from distribution to distribution_).

Answer (score 7):

Devices attached to buses such as PCI, PCMCIA and USB have an identifier that uniquely encode the manufacturer and model. Modules that contain drivers for devices attached to these buses contain information about the devices they support, in the form of a list of PCI identifiers, USB identifiers, PCMCIA identifiers, etc. When the kernel detects a device on one of these buses, it tries to load a driver for this particular identifier. More precisely, the kernel tries to load a module called (say) `usb:somelongstring` where the long string encodes the device's USB identifier. When you compile or install a kernel, the `depmod` program reads all the module file (`.ko`) that you have and generates a `modules.alias` file in `/lib/module/$VERSION/` containing lines like

```
alias usb:somelongstring uvcvideo
```

It looks like on your system, you have a driver that supports your device but the `modules.alias` file does not declare the right alias. First, run `depmod -a` to make sure that this file is up to date.

If, after than, the module is not automatically loaded but does work when it is loaded manually, then what's going on is that you have a slightly more recent model that has an unknown identifier but works with the same driver because it is sufficiently compatible with known models. In that case, report your success to the upstream developer so that the identifier is added to the next version of the driver. In the meantime, add the alias manually. You'll find the long string in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2.4.3/modalias`. Create a file called `/etc/modprobe.d/local-aliases.conf` and add the lines

```
# Microsoft LifeCam Cinema
alias usb:somelongstring uvcvideo
```

There is a [good write-up of modalias in the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Modalias).

Comment: Sweet, I didn't even know this.