# RT5572 shown in lsusb but not iwconfig

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, firmware

I've searched google and I can't find a solution to this problem :[

I'm running Debian. Simply did a minimal netinst with no desktop environment:

```
~#: uname -r
3.2.0-4-686-pae
```

I have [this product](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/cat-11_TL-WDN3200.html) which uses the Ralink 5572 chipset. According to [here](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Ralink_RT5572#Linux_support) it should be supported by the rt2800usb kernel module.

When I plug the stick in I see it come up in `dmesg` like so:

```
usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2001, idProduct=3c1a
usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-2: Product: 11n Adapter
usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Ralink
usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 1.0
```

It is also seen by `lsusb`.

And that's it. rt2800usb is not loaded (I have already run `apt-get install firmware-ralink`) On the wiki page I linked there appears to be extra stuff from dmesg. When I check `iwconfig` I don't see an interface for the device. I have also tried `modprobe rt2800usb` and the module loads no problem, but the interface still does not exist.

I can't find any errors anywhere so I can't figure out what is wrong. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your kernel doesn't have a driver for this device.

The device's model and category are recognized because these are standard USB features. Seeing them correctly identified in the output of `lsusb` doesn't imply that you have a driver that would do anything useful with the device (and contrariwise you might have a working driver and yet not see the model identification in `lsusb` if `lsusb` was working on an old database of model names).

The rt2800usb driver, like any other USB driver, registers a list of USB devices (model and manufacturer identifiers) that it can handle. Your particular model was added in [kernel 3.9](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800usb.c?v=3.9).

It's possible that merely declaring the extra model will make it work. It's also possible that this model requires a workaround in the code somewhere but there doesn't appear to be any specific treatment of that particular model in the current version, so you might have a chance.

You can force the driver to believe that it can handle your device. Once the module is loaded, [register a dynamic USB device ID](http://lwn.net/Articles/160944/):

```
echo 0x2001 0x3c1a >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id
```

To arrange for the module to be loaded automatically, you can [declare an alias for it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26132/how-to-assign-usb-driver-to-device). I think that you'd still need to register the device ID. You should be able to do that with an `install` directive in [`/etc/modprobe.d`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/modprobe.d.5.html). Create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb-local.conf` containing

```
alias usb:v2001p3c1Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* rt2800usb
install rt2800usb /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb && echo 0x2001 0x3c1a >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id
```

Comment: I'm accepting this not because it worked (haven't tried it yet) but because it's such a good answer. Thank you. My last resort was to compile a driver myself but I will try this first.

Comment: where did you get these: 0x2001 0x3c1a ?

Comment: @FernandoGabrieli From the question: `idVendor=2001, idProduct=3c1a`. I know to write the vendor and product IDs into `new_id` because of the LWN article cited in the previous sentence.