# How to autoprobe block devices in initramfs?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, initramfs, livecd

I am building a custom Alpine image based on isolinux. 
Basically, I am squashing rootfs, and mounting it as overlayfs.

Bootloader does its job fine, kernel loads, but I am stuck at initramfs. Let say I have the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
/bin/busybox --install -s

rescue_shell() {
    echo "Something went wrong. Dropping you to a shell."
    #/bin/busybox --install -s
    /bin/sh || exec /bin/busybox sh
}
mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
mount -t proc  proc /proc
mkdir  -p /dev/pts

mount -t devtmpfs -o exec,nosuid,mode=0755,size=2M devtmpfs /dev 2>/dev/null \
        || mount -t tmpfs -o exec,nosuid,mode=0755,size=2M tmpfs /dev

[ -c /dev/ptmx ] || mknod -m 666 /dev/ptmx c 5 2
[ -d /dev/pts ] || mkdir -m 755 /dev/pts
mount -t devpts -o gid=5,mode=0620,noexec,nosuid devpts /dev/pts
# shared memory area (later system will need it)
[ -d /dev/shm ] || mkdir /dev/shm
mount -t tmpfs -o nodev,nosuid,noexec shm /dev/shm

/bin/sh
# other code left for simplicity
```

So once I enters `/bin/sh`, I don't have any modules loaded, especially I am meaning for block devices, `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sr0`, which I need to mount and then extract squashed image, and mount overlay.

Listing /proc/partitions gives me only `ram[0-15]` devices, which make sense since after boot it's loaded into RAM.

So, my question would be, is there any way that devices gets probed based on available hardware? I have tried with `mdev` as well, but still can not get my block devices. Proper `mdev.conf` is there, and tests are performed in VirtualBox.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try your luck with modalias as exposed through the sysfs interface.

See for example https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/148854/ which suggests:

```
echo "/sbin/mdev" > /proc/sys/kernel/hotplug
mdev -s
find /sys/ -name modalias -print0 | xargs -0 sort -u -z | xargs -0 modprobe -abq
```

Note that I haven't tested this myself. Also this doesn't seem to be using BusyBox modprobe, which probably does not support `-ab`. Still, it might be worth checking out what your `/sys` looks like in early initramfs.

More links regarding modalias:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Modalias
- http://people.skolelinux.org/pere/blog/Modalias_strings___a_practical_way_to_map__stuff__to_hardware.html
- [How to assign USB driver to device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26132/how-to-assign-usb-driver-to-device)

Comment: Brilliant great find! Wasted at least 2 days with debug. One thing I had to do, was to recompile BusyBox from source, and set ` MODPROBE_SMALL [=n]` , so I can get more feature-able modprobe. :) Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a MODPROBE_SMALL setting in busybox. So sometimes enabling everything (=y) disables stuff. Why is it so hard to build a feature-complete busybox ...oh well. :-)